# Android Web View Crash

Tags: android, web-services, webview

My app was working fine. I had to format my computer and phone. Now the keep app crashing. I'm using a web view to display youtube everything works fine until I try to switch to full screen then I get the errors. I don't know how to solve with this problem.

```
08-10 21:41:27.005  31363-31363/? E/Zygote﹕ MountEmulatedStorage()
08-10 21:41:27.005  31363-31363/? E/Zygote﹕ v2
08-10 21:41:27.045  31363-31363/? E/SELinux﹕ [DEBUG] get_category: variable seinfo: default sensitivity: NULL, cateogry: NULL
08-10 21:41:36.865  31363-31959/com.videowebviewtest.unknown.webview_video_test E/ACodec﹕ onConfigureComponent mime.c_str() = audio/mp4a-latm
08-10 21:41:36.915  31363-31977/com.videowebviewtest.unknown.webview_video_test E/ACodec﹕ onConfigureComponent mime.c_str() = video/x-vnd.on2.vp9
08-10 21:41:36.915  31363-31977/com.videowebviewtest.unknown.webview_video_test E/ACodec﹕ [OMX.google.vp9.decoder] storeMetaDataInBuffers failed w/ err -2147483648
08-10 21:41:45.915  31363-31363/com.videowebviewtest.unknown.webview_video_test A/chromium﹕ [FATAL:jni_android.cc(271)] Check failed: false.
08-10 21:41:45.915  31363-31363/com.videowebviewtest.unknown.webview_video_test A/libc﹕ Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 31363 (view_video_test)
```